# Liferay Search Container Pagination in Liferay MVC

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui, liferay-ide

I am new to Liferay, so I need help on Search Container. In my Search Container they are two pages. After deleting a row from a liferay search container using 
`String redirectURL=themeDisplay.getURLCurrent();` it is redirecting to current page in liferay, but if there is no data in that page then it should redirect to previous page. How to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Please post code snippet,and also controller code where ur handling the redirection post deletion

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use `<liferay-ui:page-iterator>`

Comment the `<liferay-ui:page-iterator>`  tag and

uncomment the `<liferayui:search-container>` tag .  Using this after delete
record your page will be automatically refreshed and back to page you want .

**OR**

You can do one thing like change iteratorURL Value when no records are there.

For mor Information about liferay search container Follow this link.

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/05/liferay-search-container.html